# Изменить нуль-символ

Tags: c++, ассемблер, masm, intel

У меня есть нуль-терминированная строка, с указателем на первый элемент в `eax`. Я нашёл позицию, до которой необходимо обрезать строку с конца. Указатель на эту позицию хранится в `ebx`. Необходимо, чтобы строка продолжалась от `eax` до `ebx`, а не от `eax` до нуль-терминатора. Как записать в `ebx` символ `\0`?

Еще пробовал вот так:

```
mov edi, ebx
mov esi, eax
add esi, dword ptr [esp + 16] ; в esp + 16 у меня длина строки  
movsb
```

Но всё равно длина строки не изменилась.

Comment: Может просто `mov byte ptr [ebx], 0` ?

Comment: @Mike разве это не будет _число_ 0 ?

Comment: Да, будет число 0, один байт равный нулю и есть ваш нуль-символ. Как вы себе нуль-символ представляете ?

Comment: @Mike понятно, но почему-то всё равно печатает всю строку до старого нуля

Comment: Ну смотря чем печатаете, вы уверены, что оно печатает до 0 и что в ebx действительно указатель на нужное место в строке.

Comment: @Mike насчёт `ebx` уверен, потому что если попробовать записать в него какой-нибудь видимый символ, то он отображается на нужном месте; печатаю я из модуля на языке `c++` с помощью потока вывода `std::cout`. Только строка в `c++` у меня хранится в `std::string str`, а в функцию на ассемблере я передаю `str.data()`, может быть изменения размера этого массива не влияет на размер иходной строки?

Comment: Если нуль-символ попробовать напечатать то на экране он будет как пробел. Так же можно попробовать перенаправить вывод в файл посмотреть что там за символ. К сожалению с форматом хранения данных в std::string не знаком, там вполне может где нибудь отдельно быть длина и функция печати может ориентироваться на нее...

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А я вот даже не знаю, что делать. Сам текст вопроса никакого отношения к настоящей сути проблемы не имеет. А суть видимо выяснит сам автор, после экспериментов, на которые его натолкнули мои комментарии. Тогда останется полностью изменить текст вопроса и он сам сможет на него ответить :) Либо закрывать по "более не воспроизводится"

Answer (score 2):

Вы (судя по комментариям) путаете строку с нулевым завершающим байтом в языке C, и строку `string` в C++. В C++ вы формально *не имеете права* ничего делать со строкой, возвращаемой `.data()` - теоретически это может быть вообще *копия* строки, а не она сама. Но на практике обычно это проходит (хотя не буду говорить о всех компиляторах!)... только вот длина строки в `string` **не определяется** нулевым символом. Так, вполне может быть строка, состоящая из десятка нулевых символов.

Вот кусочек кода для VC++:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s("   ");
    const char * data = s.data();
    _asm {
        mov ebx, data
        mov byte ptr [ebx + 1], 0
    }
    cout << s.length() << endl;
    cout << strlen(s.c_str()) << endl;
}
```

Выводит

```
3
1
```